# ios - how to prevent app from reinstalling

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uniqueidentifier, identifier, reinstall

I make an iOS Swift app which offers some trial opportunities (e.g. 5 tries of doing something) for users to get acquainted with app capabilities. After user has run out of trial attempts, he has to buy the next ones.
How can I **remember the fact that the app had been installed earlier** by now on the **same device/with same Apple ID**?

I know that **UserDefaults** are deleted after uninstalling, and the **KeyChain** data may be deleted deliberately as well.

The user **has no need to register** for the service he or she uses, so I don't have their credentials. **UUID** isn't allowed to use as I know, and **identifierforvendor** changes after deleting as well.

Which alternatives are possible for this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that Apple doesn't accept "trial" apps into the App Store.

Comment: I dont present triap app, just a limited number of features which may me later increased with in-app purchase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with `KeyChain`, `KeyChain` will not removed after removing the application.(i.e. uninstalling application)

You can store your counts in Keychain and when the next time user install application you can get that user has used some trials.

Also

> Note: On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile
>   used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

Referenced from - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911434/will-items-in-ios-keychain-survive-app-uninstall-and-reinstall)

Comment: can the presice distinct item be deleted from the keychain manually?

Comment: No you are not able to access it, you can manage it with code only

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [In App Purchases](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/).  Then you don't have to worry about checks for deletion and reinstalling.  Just offer IAP in your app, offer 5 'credits' or what have you so they can try the specific functionality that you're offering, then block the functionality when they've run out of credits.  Allowing them to purchase more.

This will check against a specific Apple ID, but not a specific device.  However, you should let your users have the same capabilities on all their devices.  People aren't walking around with 10 iPhones AND using your app on all of them anyway.

Comment: where/how should i block functionality? If locally, after the app is deleted and reinstalled, the 'credits' will appear again.