# Firebase authentication persists across app deletion?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just released an app that uses Firebase authentication with gmail in order to authenticate users. I've noticed that if someone signs in then deletes the app, if they redownload the app they'll still be signed in with Firebase.

In my home screen's `viewDidAppear()` this is how I check whether to show the login screen or stay on this page:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
         print("~~~~~~~~~User is logged in~~~~~~~~~")
    else {
         print("User not signed in...")
         self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NotLoggedInSegue", sender: self)
    }
 }
```

I know gmail authentication persists because it is stored in the keychain, but is Firebase authentication also supposed to persist across app deletions?

Answer (score 3):

We use the keychain for storing credentials, so we're bound to the (undocumented) keychain behavior on this.

According to [Will items in iOS keychain survive app uninstall and reinstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911434/will-items-in-ios-keychain-survive-app-uninstall-and-reinstall) this is expected behavior, but may have changed with 10.3.