# When uninstall app, all certificated related to that app get also deleted iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, keychain, digital-certificate

I am making an app in which i have to install digital certificates in keychain of iOS.
So, my question is that if i **uninstall** the application then the **certificate** which is related to my app also get **deleted** from **keychain** or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will items in iOS keychain survive app uninstall and reinstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911434/will-items-in-ios-keychain-survive-app-uninstall-and-reinstall)

Comment: Thanks Nishant for ur instant reply. But in that question too there are not sure what going to be happen because it is not documented anywhere.