# To Identify an iOS device uniquely even after uninstallation of application for packages purposes

Tags: ios, swift, unique, uniqueidentifier

I need to identify an iOS Device uniquely through swift that the identification remains same even user uninstall and reinstall the application again and again the unique identifier for that device should not change

Answer (score 2):

Since the value returned from `identifierForVendor` can be cleared when deleting the app or reset if the user resets it in the Settings app, you have to manage persisting it yourself.

You can create your own UDID and store it locally in the `keychain`.

Please check this :

[How to get the realy fixed Device-ID in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641614/how-to-get-the-realy-fixed-device-id-in-swift)