# How to check whether the app had been downloaded before on iOS12 device

Tags: ios, privacy

I came up with this question when I see some stores advertising customers to download their apps, then sign in to get a voucher, but if the customer delete and reinstall the app, they won't get the voucher again.

I know before iOS10.3, developer can store the device info to a keychain, but according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18911434/will-items-in-ios-keychain-survive-app-uninstall-and-reinstall), apple changed this rule, so the keychain is not persistent anymore. Also, I don't think apple will allow app has access to the device id? Now, what are some ways the developer can identify the user had downloaded the app on the same device before?

Comment: At this time, keychain data is persisted across re-installs.  The better solution, moving forward, is the DeviceCheck framework.

Comment: may be you can do it using UDID of device when app is launch store udid in your data base and check it if udid exist in database or not